# Mobile Push App + Inbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, mobilepush

We have a requirement to send a Push ALert + message to a certain path in the mobile App.
I see 2 options : Mobile Push notification ( App URL) and Alert +Inbox message.

The alert+Inbox has a mandatory Cloud page needed, i am trying to understand what that means. If i click on the push alert and it gets redirected to that cloud page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Push notification informs the user something is happening in the App, it redirects the user to the App.
The Inbox message provides the associated Cloud Page URL via the SDK which you can use to display the Inbox inside the App or to redirect the user to it, up to you.

Keep in mind the 2 following considerations:

1. Inbox + Push counts for 2 super messages
2. In order to use Inbox + Push in Journey Builder, the inbox message must be created with the "Interaction" send type, which is not always activated (support ticket in that case)

Comment: How can i get inbox message without Cloud page?

Comment: You can't as it is a required parameter, but you can create an empty one and not use it in you app.

Comment: wouldnt the URL show up ? can the app dev team hijack the code and not show it ? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, check https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android (InboxViewer class), the Kotlin learning APP. The app display the Inbox URL inside a web view, but could display anything else or nothing at all.